# How to find all rows contains certain substring, Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a series look like:

```
10        1.01
12     C201311
20        1.02
21      2A8272
22      2A8067
        ...   
370     G26907
373     G20617
374     G20618
376     G20617
377     G20618
```

in short, all rows contain "." is unwanted

I was trying apply count() method but no luck
`df["Part No."].count(".") > 0`

Anyone has idea how I can get rid of unwanted rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `contains`

```
m=df["Part No."].str.contains('[.]')
df=df[m]
```

Also `df["Part No."].str.count('[.]') > 0` work as well

Comment: Work like a charm!
But where I can find some docs about using contains('[.]') instead of contains('.')?

Comment: @Yang contains with dot, in regex means count all the character in the string , ps : if this answer help would you like upvote and accept ?"